# creating a timer when firing a function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I'd like to create some sort of timer that will take the time between firing different kind of functions but I'm having no such luck so far.  I assumed I should use the `NSDate` object and I've done this so far.

I've created several functions

```
-(void)startTime:(id)sender
{
    starttime = [NSDate date];
    **[starttime retain];**   
    NSLog(@"show me the starttime %f", starttime);
}

-(void)endTime:(id)sender
{
    endtime = [NSDate date];
    **[endtime retain];**
    NSLog(@"show me the endtime %f", endtime);
}

-(void)timeInterval:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval interval = [ starttime timeIntervalSinceDate:endtime];   
    NSLog(@"let me see the timeinterval between now and then %f", interval);
}
```

For instance when I press a playbutton which will play a movie 
I will place the `starttime` function

```
-(void)playMovie:(id)sender
{
 [self startTime:(id)sender];
[self callMovie];
}
```

And when I press a stopbutton for the movie the `stopfunction` will be called as will the `timeInterval` function

```
-(void)stopMovie:(id)sender
{
[self endTime:(id)sender]; 
[self myMovie];

[self timeInterval:(id)sender];
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work. If I press the stopbutton after 3 seconds I would assume my 
function `timeInterval` would give an output of 3 seconds. Unfortunately to no avail.
What's going on, and what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the responses.
I made some adjustments in my code snippets.

However I seem to have made a crucial error.  I wasn't retaining `endtime` and `starttime` variables and this seems to have solved my case.

Comment: It's usually helpful to tell us what the wrong behavior is that you're actually seeing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple program using your example timing functions and sleep 3 yields -3.000087

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you press the stopbutton? If nothing happens, check your IBOutlets, the action is probably not hooked up to the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)stopMovie:(id)sender {
    [self endTime:(id)sender]; 
    [self myMovie];
    [self timeInterval:(id)sender];
}
```

Shouldn't you be calling endTime instead of stopTime?